# For loop array iteration, if loop tests if indices is true/false, evaluating true incorrectly

Tags: c++, arrays, if-statement, for-loop, switch-statement

I'm working on an inventory system as a challenge for the amount of c++ I currently know, I'm using an array with enumerated indices and initializing with value true or false. This is the code:

```
using namespace std;

enum items
{
    LASER_RIFLE,
    LASER_SWORD,
    LASER_PISTOL,
    PLASMA_LAUNCHER,
    MAX_ITEMS
};


void playerInventory()
{
    bool items[MAX_ITEMS];
    items[LASER_RIFLE] = true;
    items[LASER_SWORD] = false;
    items[LASER_PISTOL] = false;
    items[PLASMA_LAUNCHER] = true;

    int itemName;
    for (int item = 0; item <= MAX_ITEMS; ++item)
        if (items[item] == true)
        {
            switch (itemName)
            {
            case 1:
                cout << "Laser Rifle\n";
                break;
            case 2:
                cout << "Laser Sword\n";
                break;
            case 3:
                cout << "Laser Pistol\n";
                break;
            case 4:
                cout << "Plasma Launcher \n";
                break;
            }
        }
        else
            cout << "Not in Inventory\n";
}
```

The statement only evaluates true for Laser pistol, and false for everything else. I cannot figure out why this is.

Comment: you put swtich(itemName). never changes in loop.

Answer (score 1):

- You are switching for `itemName`. You should switch for `item`
- Enumeration on default starts with 0, not 1. Your cases should start from 0.
- In for loop you have to check against `<` not `<=`.

Here is the result:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

enum items
{
    LASER_RIFLE,
    LASER_SWORD,
    LASER_PISTOL,
    PLASMA_LAUNCHER,
    MAX_ITEMS
};


void playerInventory()
{
    bool items[MAX_ITEMS];
    items[LASER_RIFLE] = true;
    items[LASER_SWORD] = false;
    items[LASER_PISTOL] = false;
    items[PLASMA_LAUNCHER] = true;

    int itemName;
    for (int item = 0; item < MAX_ITEMS; ++item) {
        if (items[item] == true)
        {
            switch (item)
            {
            case 0:
                cout << "Laser Rifle\n";
                break;
            case 1:
                cout << "Laser Sword\n";
                break;
            case 2:
                cout << "Laser Pistol\n";
                break;
            case 3:
                cout << "Plasma Launcher \n";
                break;
            }
        }
        else {
            cout << "Not in Inventory\n";
        }
    }
}

int main() {
    playerInventory();
    return 0;
}
```

See: [ideone](http://ideone.com/ogIAcA)

Comment: Thank you for the fast response, I appreciate the thoroughness of your answer. Like I said, I'm relatively new to C++, I understand the enumeration problem and the itemName problem, but what i don't get is why it was evaluating to true for only Laser Pistol, i know initialized variables screw things up, but it was still not working when i had itemName = item. Thank's for your help.

Comment: @SawyerAdlaiVierra-Hatch "it was evaluating to true for only Laser Pistol" is false.  It was not evaluating true for Laser Pistol. The code was entering in if case when item was 0 and 3. There was no problem there. You just saw "Laser Pistol" print coincidentally, not because it was evaluated to true. How could itemName be evaluated as 3 and you saw that print.. Who knows? It tells you, it is undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

You never assign anything to itemName.

> Change switch(itemName) to switch(item).

Answer (score 0):

You've two places invoking [undefined behaviour](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2397984/183120):

1. `item <= MAX_ITEMS` should be `item < MAX_ITEMS`; otherwise you'd be accessing the array beyond its bounds.
2. Accessing an uninitialized variable: `itemName`.

Once you've undefined behaviour, all bets are off. Do not expect any sane output from the program.

Answer (score 0):

itemName is never initialized so use itemName INSIDE the for scope and equalize the true ones with it or directly change it with item.

Oh and you are looking for a place that is beyond your arrays bounds. The array's length may be `MAX_ITEMS` long but your indices start from 0. So you should use `item < MAX_ITEMS` instead of `item <= MAX_ITEMS`.

Btw: you may want to use default for your switch-case structure. Not necessary for this one but it can be a lifesaver.

Comment: I can't believe I forgot that, I guess it just come with starting out. I hate it when i forget silly stuff like that though. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Bad things happen mate. That's the best way to learn though. Good luck with your work